# Azure functions settings

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to add an environment variable to azure functions, there is the "local.settings.json", but it's only for local development, though the documentation doesn't give any clue as to how I can set settings in production.

Any documentation about environment variable only explains how to READ environment variables, but I wish to WRITE an environment variable...

If no such file option exists, is it possible to set environment variables using the AZ cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options and it depends a bit how you are deploying your function to Azure.

### Azure CLI

```
az functionapp config appsettings set [--ids]
                                      [--name]
                                      [--resource-group]
                                      [--settings]
                                      [--slot]
                                      [--slot-settings]
                                      [--subscription]
```

Where the `-settings` argument contains space separated `name=value` pairs.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-config-appsettings-set

### Azure Function Core Tools

This publishes your function app including your local settings to the cloud:

`func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName> --publish-local-settings`

This publishes only your local settings to your function app in the cloud:

`func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName> --publish-settings-only`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#project-file-deployment

### Azure DevOps

If you're using Azure DevOps with Release Pipelines the Azure Function App task is convenient to use:

Supply the settings as space separated `-key value` pairs in the `appSettings` parameter in the task.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-function-app?view=azure-devops

### The Azure Portal

As Matt described you could add/update using the Azure Portal as well via **Configuration -> Application Settings** but I recommend against that if you're doing automated deployments (which you should ;).

Comment: Fair point, it didn’t feel like this question was quite at that stage but as it happens I’d recommend ARM templates over these! ;)

Comment: With a bit of Azure DevOps over the top if need be for customising different environments....

Comment: The "settings" here can be accessed through environment variables? this isn't obvious at all, and the docs don't mention it anywhere

Comment: @LironNavon yes indeed: It's a bit hidden in the documentation. Have a look at these docs for [C# .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#environment-variables) and for [Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#environment-variables).

Comment: @Matt ARM templates is also a good alternative indeed. The OP didn't provide much context about CI/CD so why not list many different possibilities :).

Answer (score 0):

To add the equivalent settings into Azure you need to create the setting under Configuration:

[image]

There are some issues/inconsistencies with how settings work in Azure for Azure Functions, see [this github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/32962) for more info, for example if you're trying to use a connection string with GetEnvironmentVariable you actually need to put this in as a normal setting in Azure e.g.:

[image]

Comment: These configurations are accessible through environment variables? they are not just for azure?