# Where to put my Azure storage account queue connectionstring (used by my Azure function)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure storage account with a queue in it.
Now in my function (created in Visual Studio) I have this:

```
    public IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
        HttpRequest req,
        [Queue("temperatuurmeting"), StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")]
        ICollector<string> messages,
        ILogger log)
    {
    `
```

I host the code in BitBucket, and when I commit something it gets deployed to Azure, and it works.

But.... the `AzureWebJobsStorage` connection string is (automatically created when I created my function in Visual Studio) in the `local.settings.json`, which I just read should not be in the code repository.

But: when I do not include the `local.settings.json` in de code repo, and then deploy it to Azure, where should I put the `AzureWebJobsStorage` connectionstring so that my running function can find it?

Or is `AzureWebJobsStorage` a default name and already somewhere in Azure created by something other than me and can I just remove the `local.settings.json`?

Comment: You have several options how and where to define your application settings such as this connection string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901504/azure-functions-settings/56904666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally:

```
"Connection": "Endpoint=sb://****.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=****;SharedAccessKey=*********"
```

in local.settings.json

```
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("attended", Connection = "Connection")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
```

in the function

When you publish go to the portal 
go to your function app settings
[variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBYCf.png)

and then add the variable you used

Comment: Thanks very much for the image! Why didn't I think of this myself :-( Must have been there 20 times (searching for other stuff :-)) never connected the dots....